# How current state is managed in ConversationHandler in python-telegram-api

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I want to use a [ConversationHandler](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html) in my bot. At least, it would need three parameters:

```
class telegram.ext.ConversationHandler(entry_points, states, fallbacks)
```

AFAIK, entry points are triggers for the conversation handler, then each state may execute its own handlers, and [based on fallbacks definition](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html#telegram.ext.ConversationHandler.fallbacks), if all handlers from a state return `false`, then fallback is triggered.

Ok, therefore, handlers return something. But a handler is an object, an instance of a class.

Based on [this example](https://github.com/guysoft/AlarmBot/blob/master/src/alarm_bot.py), looking for example to the `new_alarm_handler`.

### So my doubts

1. How is it, that handlers return a value? (They appear to return their callback function result).
2. Where is the current state of the conversation? It appears to not be accessible, but to be the last result of the last handler executed. Is it it? If not, then what do I have to do to change the current state in the conversation?
3. Therefore, when a state is reached, their list of handlers (value in the dictionary `states` passed as arg) is executed. But being a list, it could be more than one, so there could be more than one returned state. How is it managed?

Answer (score 6):

ConversationHandler stores the current `state` of the conversation in a dict, called `conversations`, and the key is an entity called `conversation_key`. It is a tuple, that consists of Chat's ID, User's ID and Message's ID (Some of which may be missing, this is defined by `per_chat`, `per_user` and `per_message` bool attributes).

Here `conversations` is accessed to get `state` in `check_update` method (explained further):
https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/2cde878d1e5e0bb552aaf41d5ab5df695ec4addb/telegram/ext/conversationhandler.py#L248
The state of the conversation is not intended to be accessible manually.

When user sends a message to the bot, `Updater` receives `Update` objects from Telegram and delivers them to its `Dispatcher`. `Dispatcher` has a list of registered `Handler` objects, their `check_update` methods are called in order in which they were added. `check_update` either returns `False` or `None` if the update should not be handled, or it returns some object that is then passed to `handle_update` method.

`ConversationHandler` inherits from `Handler` itself and it has other `Handler` objects as values in its `states` dict. It also has `check_update` and `handle_update` overwritten. Its `check_update` gets its current conversation `state` (see link above) and calls the `check_update` methods of all the handlers for that `state`. If all of them return `False` it does the same for handlers in `fallbacks` list. If all their check also return `False` it does nothing.

If one of the handlers should handle the event, the object its `check_update` returns is passed to `ConversationHadler`'s `handle_update` method. It calls the fired `Handler`'s `handle_update` method, which in turn calls the callback function, defined on its creation. Its result is set to be the new `state` of this conversation in the `conversations` dict.

According to the ConversationHandler docstring:

``` To change the state of conversation, the callback function of a handler must return the new state after responding to the user. If it does not return anything (returning ``None`` by default), the state will not change. ```